Use dynamic formula to count consecutive instances (based on criteria) in a dynamic row
I have a sheet in Excel consisting of staff planning data. This sheet is a direct import from our time registration tool, so any structural changes have to be made based on this raw data.
This sheet contains various columns:

name
day of week
date
planned schedule for the day
time registration for the day
absence code if applicable

Raw data input
RAW DATA INPUT IN TEXT FORMAT:



Name
Day
Date
Planned schedule
Register
Code




EMPLOYEE1
MON
18/03/2024
Day1
07:38   16:00
0


EMPLOYEE1
TUE
19/03/2024
Day1
07:41   16:00
0


EMPLOYEE1
WED
20/03/2024
Day1
07:40   16:00
0


EMPLOYEE1
THU
21/03/2024
Day1
07:40   16:00
0


EMPLOYEE1
FRI
22/03/2024
Day1
0
OFF


EMPLOYEE1
SAT
23/03/2024
NOPLAN




EMPLOYEE1
SUN
24/03/2024
NOPLAN




EMPLOYEE1
MON
25/03/2024
Day1
07:40   16:00
0


EMPLOYEE1
TUE
26/03/2024
Day1
07:37   16:00
0


EMPLOYEE1
WED
27/03/2024
Day1
07:42   16:00
0


EMPLOYEE1
THU
28/03/2024
Day1
0
0


EMPLOYEE1
FRI
29/03/2024
Day1
0
0


EMPLOYEE1
SAT
30/03/2024
NOPLAN




EMPLOYEE1
SUN
31/03/2024
NOPLAN




EMPLOYEE2
MON
18/03/2024
Day1
0
0


EMPLOYEE2
TUE
19/03/2024
Day1
0
0


EMPLOYEE2
WED
20/03/2024
Day1
0
0


EMPLOYEE2
THU
21/03/2024
Day1
0
OFF


EMPLOYEE2
FRI
22/03/2024
Day1
0
0


EMPLOYEE2
SAT
23/03/2024
NOPLAN
0
OFF


EMPLOYEE2
SUN
24/03/2024
NOPLAN
0
0


EMPLOYEE2
MON
25/03/2024
Day1
0
OFF


EMPLOYEE2
TUE
26/03/2024
Day1
0
OFF


EMPLOYEE2
WED
27/03/2024
Day1
0
OFF


EMPLOYEE2
THU
28/03/2024
Day1
07:41   16:00
0


EMPLOYEE2
FRI
29/03/2024
Day1
09:29   16:00 *
OFF


EMPLOYEE2
SAT
30/03/2024
NOPLAN
07:45   19:02
0


EMPLOYEE2
SUN
31/03/2024
NOPLAN
07:54   16:00
0



I use another sheet with formulas to run several 'checks' based on this input sheet.
Recently I've been on a mission to redo a lot of these 'checks' using only dynamic formulas so we reduce the error rate due to formulas not being pulled down in the case of bigger-than-normal data.
I cannot figure out how to redo the following check using only dynamic formulas in Excel...
The idea is that staff is allowed to not register any hours without also registering a reason for said absence for a maximum of two consecutive workdays. The reasoning is that those hours are automatically deducted from overtime. If they are absent for more than 2 days (= no time registration) AND if they have no reason for absence registered, my check should result in a signal: I need to return the row where this occurs.
What I have working now is:

dynamic filter formula to filter the raw data to remove rows with no planned schedule because those are not relevant
check whether a row qualifies as a row that needs to be signaled: if there is a schedule and there is no  time registration and there is no reason for absence then mark that row with a helper column (TRUE or 1) (basically AND((D:D>0);(E:E=0);(F:F=0))
check who has more than 2 consecutive marked rows

I have this check working right now but the last check (mark more then 2 consecutive positive rows) is a pull-down formula, it is not a dynamic one. I just mark the signaled rows with a 1 and then IF the row is a signaled row, sum that 1 with the previous row. This way if there are 4 consecutive signaled rows, the rows add to 1, 2, 3, 4 and then reset to 0 on the next non-signaled row.
I cannot figure out how to make it dynamic but would really like to convert it so I can stop worrying about someone one day not pulling it down far enough to account for all date.
The end-result of this check is then output to another sheet based with a filter formula (show all rows that have a value higher than 2 when checking the consecutive rows).
What the desired output in the helper columns should/could look like, 'Desired output' is what I have working now with the pull-down formula
DESIRED OUTPUT IN TEXT FORMAT:



Name
Day
Date
Planned schedule
Register
Code
Signal row
Desired output
Desired output 2




EMPLOYEE1
MON
18/03/2024
Day1
07:38   16:00
0





EMPLOYEE1
TUE
19/03/2024
Day1
07:41   16:00
0





EMPLOYEE1
WED
20/03/2024
Day1
07:40   16:00
0





EMPLOYEE1
THU
21/03/2024
Day1
07:40   16:00
0





EMPLOYEE1
FRI
22/03/2024
Day1
0
OFF





EMPLOYEE1
SAT
23/03/2024
NOPLAN







EMPLOYEE1
SUN
24/03/2024
NOPLAN







EMPLOYEE1
MON
25/03/2024
Day1
07:40   16:00
0





EMPLOYEE1
TUE
26/03/2024
Day1
07:37   16:00
0





EMPLOYEE1
WED
27/03/2024
Day1
07:42   16:00
0





EMPLOYEE1
THU
28/03/2024
Day1
0
0
1
1



EMPLOYEE1
FRI
29/03/2024
Day1
0
0
1
2



EMPLOYEE1
SAT
30/03/2024
NOPLAN







EMPLOYEE1
SUN
31/03/2024
NOPLAN







EMPLOYEE2
MON
18/03/2024
Day1
0
0
1
1



EMPLOYEE2
TUE
19/03/2024
Day1
0
0
1
2



EMPLOYEE2
WED
20/03/2024
Day1
0
0
1
3
1


EMPLOYEE2
THU
21/03/2024
Day1
0
OFF





EMPLOYEE2
FRI
22/03/2024
Day1
0
0
1
1



EMPLOYEE2
SAT
23/03/2024
NOPLAN
0
OFF





EMPLOYEE2
SUN
24/03/2024
NOPLAN
0
0
1
1



EMPLOYEE2
MON
25/03/2024
Day1
0
OFF





EMPLOYEE2
TUE
26/03/2024
Day1
0
OFF





EMPLOYEE2
WED
27/03/2024
Day1
0
OFF





EMPLOYEE2
THU
28/03/2024
Day1
07:41   16:00
0





EMPLOYEE2
FRI
29/03/2024
Day1
09:29   16:00 *
OFF





EMPLOYEE2
SAT
30/03/2024
NOPLAN
07:45   19:02
0





EMPLOYEE2
SUN
31/03/2024
NOPLAN
07:54   16:00
0







For desired 1 you can use =SCAN(0,G2:G29,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b=1,a+1,0)))
For desired 2 you can use =IF(H2#>3,1,"")
Desired 1 will output zeros (0) instead of blank spaces, but you could hide them in various ways if you desire to do so.

EDIT:
I'm not sure if your 'Signal Row' formula is dynamic, but if it is, you can use G2# instead of G2:G29.

EDIT 3: (for future references, but based on what you found yourself):
=SCAN(0;G2#;LAMBDA(a;b;IF(AND(NOT(EQUAL(OFFSET(b;0;-6);OFFSET(b;-1;-6)));b=1);0+1;IF(b=1;a+1;0))))
With G2# referencing to the Signal row column, and -6 is the offset between Signal row and Name.

EDIT 2:
Using a table, enter this formula in the second last column:
=IF(AND([@Name]=A54,[@[Signal row]]=1),H54+1,[@[Signal row]])
And in the last column:
=IF(]@Kolom1]>2,"FLAG","")


Hah, I had tried our good friend Google before and concluded that LAMBDA would be part of the solution but couldn't figure it out. Thanks a lot, it's working now! Will read into lambda a bit more because it seems I will be using this a lot more in the future...
Also, I would upvote your answer but I have insufficient reputation apparently...

Alas... It works for everything I asked BUT there is a new issue which I had accounted for in my old formula that I did not mention before. The problem arises when an employee has 'signaled' rows as the last rows and the next employee has the first row(s) also as 'signaled' rows. The formula just keeps counting instead of resetting at the new employee and starting again from 1. I know how to handle this in a normal non-dynamic formula but have no idea how to do it with this one.

@AIMB0X2 have you considered using Tables instead? I've added in an answer based on tables. Since tables reshape and insert formulas automatically.

Thank you for your efforts. I had not considered using Tables because I thought such a way would not provide the required 'automatisation'. The general idea would be to only have to paste the raw data input in the input sheet and then only look at the output sheet (based on filter formula) without any manuel actions in between. Would this be possible to obtain using Tables?

@AIMB0X2 From what I can see with the given data and what you're trying to achieve, I think tables will work just fine. Just make sure you don't paste your data over the formula columns and you should be fine. The table size will automatically resize (although only grow) to the data copied in.

I was trying to get the lambda to work and I found a post on the interwebs detailing how to reset the lambda function on the start of a new fiscal year. I applied that to the name of the employee (reset at a new name) and this gave:
SCAN(0;O3#;LAMBDA(a;b;IF(AND(NOT(EQUAL(OFFSET(b;0;-13);OFFSET(b;-1;-13)));b=1);0+1;IF(b=1;a+1;0))))  So basically it does what you posted but there is an extra IF before: IF the name of the previous person  is not equal to the name of the current person AND b=1 then do 0+1 instead of a+1.
Do you see any problems with this setup?

@AIMB0X2 that seems to work indeed, did you figure out how to apply it? Or do you want me to edit it in the answer?

It seems to work for now, I added it to the column where I previously had the first version of the formula and it resolved the issue of the continued counting. So until I encounter new problems, this is an excellent solution. Thanks for all of your help!
